# Split list into tabular with luatex

Tags: luatex

I'm looking for a luatex solution doing something like this.

```
\split{a;b;c;d;e}
```

This command should produce a tabular like this one.

```
\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c|}}
\hline
a & b & c & d & e \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I'm trying with such a code, but I have many problems with compiling and debuging is not very easy.

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{luatextra}

\newcommand{\split}[1]{%
\directlua{
    lst = string.split("#1",";")
    max = \luaescapestring{##lst}
    tex.print(format.string([[\string\begin{tabular}{|*{\%i}{c|}]],max))
    tex.print([[\string\hline]])
    for i,x in ipairs(lst) do
         if i == max then
             tex.print(format.string([[\%s \string\string\]],x)
         else
             tex.print(format.string([[\%s \&]],x)
         end
    end
    tex.print([[\string\hline]])
    tex.print([[\string\end{tabular}]])}}

\begin{document}
\split{a;b;c;d;e}
\end{document}
```

Edit 1 : The following code is working for me.

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{luatextra}

\begin{luacode*}
  function split(input)
    local lst = string.split(input,";")
    local max = #lst
    tex.print(string.format([[\begin{tabular}{|*{%i}{c|}}]],max))
    tex.print([[\hline]])
    for i, x in ipairs(lst) do
       if i == max then
         tex.print(string.format([[%s \\]],x))
       else
         tex.print(string.format([[%s & ]],x))
       end
    end
    tex.print([[\hline\end{tabular}]])
  end
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand{\split}[1]{\directlua{split("#1")}}

\begin{document}
\split{a;b;c;d;e}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this essentially a learning exercise? That is, you are just trying to learn Lua rather than solve the problem you specifically mention? Otherwise, why the insistence on Lua?

Comment: Yes, this is an exercice and i'm trying to learn lua. I need to understand some things about directlua and special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua's `string` does not have a `split` function by default. See [Split Join](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin) for numerous design and implementation examples.

Writing Lua in TeX makes escaping of special characters an issue.
Package [`luacode`](http://ctan.org/pkg/luacode) provides several methods and environments for writing Lua code. Its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/luatex/latex/luacode/luacode.pdf) provides an overview, how which character in each method are escaped.

Since it's an exercise, the following example does not use `luatextra` or `luacode` and used the primitive `\directlua` directly.

The special characters:

- The percent sign `%` is the comment character in TeX, therefore the example defines `\%` to expand to the percent character.
- `\#` is defined as escape for the hash character.
- `\\` is defined as escape for the backslash. Caution: Some methods of `luacode` use the input `\\` for the *double* double backslash and use `\string\` for the single backslash except for environment `luacode*`, where the backslash is written in verbatim manner.

Since TeX would replaces line ends by spaces, the code in `\directlua` would be one huge line for Lua and errors are always reported in the first line.
Therefore the end of line behavior is changed inside a group to make a new line character (LF/0x10) instead. Because TeX reads a complete line *before* executing the contents of the line, the percent comment after the final `\endgroup` disables the read end line character. Otherwise the new line character would be seen by TeX as normal character, causing the error `Missing`\begin{document}`, if used in the preamble or the end of line would go as character (slot 10 of the current font) in the typeset output.

Full example:

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{article}

% Function string:split
%
% Source: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin (GavinKistner)
%
% Written for 5.0; could be made slightly cleaner with 5.1
% Splits a string based on a separator string or pattern;
% returns an array of pieces of the string.
% (May optionally supply a table as the third parameter
% which will be filled with the results.)
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \let\%\@percentchar
  \let\\\@backslashchar
  \edef\#{\string#}%
  \catcode10=12 %
  \endlinechar=10 %
\directlua{%
  function string:split( inSplitPattern, outResults )
    if not outResults then
      outResults = { }
    end
    local theStart = 1
    local theSplitStart, theSplitEnd = string.find( self, inSplitPattern, theStart )
    while theSplitStart do
      table.insert( outResults, string.sub( self, theStart, theSplitStart-1 ) )
      theStart = theSplitEnd + 1
      theSplitStart, theSplitEnd = string.find( self, inSplitPattern, theStart )
    end
    table.insert( outResults, string.sub( self, theStart ) )
    return outResults
  end
}\directlua{%
  function semicolon_split(input)
    local lst = input:split(";")
    local max = \#lst
    tex.print(string.format([[\\begin{tabular}{|*{\%i}{c|}}]],max))
    tex.print([[\\hline ]])
    for i, x in ipairs(lst) do
       if i == max then
         tex.print(string.format([[\%s\\\\]],x))
       else
         tex.print(string.format([[\%s&]],x))
       end
    end
    tex.print([[\\hline\\end{tabular}]])
  end
}\endgroup%

\newcommand{\split}[1]{%
  \directlua{semicolon_split("\luatexluaescapestring{#1}")}%
}

\begin{document}
\split{a;b;c;d;e}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

For comparison, the same with environment `luacode`. There, `%` and `#` can be used directly or used as `\%` and `\#`. The backslash is available via the longer `\string\`, more correctly, `\` is not a valid token, thus `\string` is applied to the next command starting with `\`. The macro `\\` generates the double backslash.

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

% Function string:split
%
% Source: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin (GavinKistner)
%
% Written for 5.0; could be made slightly cleaner with 5.1
% Splits a string based on a separator string or pattern;
% returns an array of pieces of the string.
% (May optionally supply a table as the third parameter
% which will be filled with the results.)
\begin{luacode}
  function string:split( inSplitPattern, outResults )
    if not outResults then
      outResults = { }
    end
    local theStart = 1
    local theSplitStart, theSplitEnd = string.find( self, inSplitPattern,
    theStart )
    while theSplitStart do
      table.insert( outResults, string.sub( self, theStart, theSplitStart-1 ) )
      theStart = theSplitEnd + 1
      theSplitStart, theSplitEnd = string.find( self, inSplitPattern, theStart )
    end
    table.insert( outResults, string.sub( self, theStart ) )
    return outResults
  end
\end{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
  function semicolon_split(input)
    local lst = input:split(";")
    local max = #lst
    tex.print(string.format([[\string\begin{tabular}{|*{%i}{c|}}]],max))
    tex.print([[\\hline ]])
    for i, x in ipairs(lst) do
       if i == max then
         tex.print(string.format([[%s\\]],x))
       else
         tex.print(string.format([[%s&]],x))
       end
    end
    tex.print([[\string\hline\string\end{tabular}]])
  end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\split}[1]{%
  \luadirect{semicolon_split("\luatexluaescapestring{#1}")}%
}

\begin{document}
\split{a;b;c;d;e}
\end{document}
```

Environment `luacode*` is probably the easiest to use, if TeX macros, TeX parameters, ... are not needed:

```
\begin{luacode*}
  function semicolon_split(input)
    local lst = input:split(";")
    local max = #lst
    tex.print(string.format([[\begin{tabular}{|*{%i}{c|}}]],max))
    tex.print([[\hline ]])
    for i, x in ipairs(lst) do
       if i == max then
         tex.print(string.format([[%s\\]],x))
       else
         tex.print(string.format([[%s&]],x))
       end
    end
    tex.print([[\hline\end{tabular}]])
  end
\end{luacode*}
```

Comment: +1. A version of the answer, which loads the `luacode` package and uses a `luacode` or `luacode*` environment to house the Lua code, might be instructive as well.

Comment: @Mico Version with package `luacode` added.

Comment: Is `tex.print(string.format([[%s\\]],x))` needed in the `luacode` and `luacode*` environments? I would write, `tex.print(x.."\\\\")`. (`x` is a string by construction.)

Comment: @Mico Then the percent sign would be gone ;-) Yes, string concatenation would simplify the code.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Are you sure there is no string.split() function ? Because the code I added in "Edit 1" is working.

Comment: @MB78 I got `! LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: attempt to call field 'split' (a nil value)` for `string.split(...)` with LuaTeX beta-0.80.0.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek : I'm using the same version `This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238)  (format=lualatex 2016.4.4)`. I don't know why I din't get any Luatex error ...

Comment: @MB78 Package `luatextra` loads the library `lualibs` (`\usepackage{luatexbase}\RequireLuaModule{lualibs}`), which defines the `split` function (`lualibs-lpeg.lua`).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek : So no error with `\usepackage{luatextra}` ? The problem is solved and the 'best' answer is the one in "Edit 1" I think. Thank you again.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek : I think there is an extra backslash in `tex.print([[\\hline ]])` inside the `luacode*` solution.

Comment: I think you can also do away with the brace groups (`[[`...`]]`) and just write doubled backslashes wherever it's necessary to ouput ` \ `.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I guess you know of `string.explode()` to split the string?! It is built into LuaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

LuaTeX has `string.explode()` to make a table of strings from one string with a separator, suitable for your case. (See the documentation of LuaTeX for that).

But your question is much simpler to answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
split=function(inputstr)
    local str,cnt = string.gsub(inputstr,";"," & ")
    tex.sprint("\\begin{tabular}{|*{",cnt + 1,"}{c|}}")
    tex.sprint("\\hline", str, "\\\\\\hline\\end{tabular}")
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\split}[1]{\luaexec{split(\luastring{#1})}}

\begin{document}
\split{a;b;c;d;e}
\end{document}
```

You can substitute the `;`  with `&` in your string.

Result:

[image: tablewithcharacters]

---

Edit1: replaced the long `"\lualatexescapestring{..}"` with the much simpler `\luastring{..}` defined in the luacode package. Thanks to Mico for that hint.
Edit2: make function more generic

Comment: @Mico where is `\luastring{}` defined? Is it “new”?  – I see, I should read the fine `luacode` manual. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Thanks for this new answer. That's good but the number of tabular cols isn't necessary 5.

Comment: @MB78 That's easy, I'll edit my post in a second