# Table with unknown number of rows

Tags: tables, optional-arguments

I (a LaTeX noob) am trying to create a command that I will call as follows:

```
$\machine{a_1}{a_2}{\vdots}{a_n}$
```

with a variable number of arguments, which will output

```
$\begin{array}{|c|}
   \hline a_1 \\ \hline
   a_2        \\ \hline
   \vdots     \\ \hline
   a_n        \\ \hline
 \end{array}$
```

with one row for each argument to `\machine`.

As my first try at something that seemed vaguely in the right area, the best I could come up with was:

```
\newcommand{\machine}[1]{\begin{array}{|c|}
  \foreach \index in {1, ..., #1} {
    \index \\
  } 
\end{array}}
```

which I couldn't get to compile anyway. (As I say, I'm a LaTeX noob.)

How can such a command be made? (I'd be happy with any sensible calling syntax; it doesn't have to be `\machine{}{}{}` if that makes it more difficult.)

Comment: Why not something like `\machine{a_1, a_2, \vdots, a_n}`?  It would make life easier.  Otherwise, how does the macro know when the end of the array list comes?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Your point is obvious once you say it, but I didn't realise it at the time. Thank you.

Comment: If you can use LuaLaTeX, you should also have a look at the recent posting [Split list into tabular with luatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304536/5001).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loops with `tabular` or `array` are always tricky -- either use a token variable and store the whole table in the `token` register or do other weird tricks or ...

... use `\prg_replicate:nn` from `LaTeX 3` (well `expl3` rather) and let the loop be done.

I've defined `\machine{}` to get one argument, regarded it's content as comma - separated list and stored the content the into a `clist` variable, which is traversed inside of `\prg_replicate:nn`.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N\g_patrick_int%

\NewDocumentCommand{\machine}{m}{%
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
  \int_gzero:N \g_patrick_int 
  \begin{array}{|c|}
    \hline
    \prg_replicate:nn { \clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist } {%
      \int_gincr:N \g_patrick_int 
      \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { \g_patrick_int }  \\
      \hline
    }
  \end{array}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\machine{a_1, a_2, \vdots, a_n} \neq \machine{a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, \vdots, a_n}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Shorter version**

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\machine}{m}{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \begin{array}{|c|}
    \hline
    \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\\ \hline} %
    \\ \hline
  \end{array}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\machine{a_1, a_2, \vdots, a_n} \neq \machine{a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, \vdots, a_n}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need; thank you. I'm very impressed. I'm a programmer who is used to LaTeX as a typesetting environment, but doing any programming (even the most trivial) in LaTeX just seems to collapse my brain. I'll accept your answer tomorrow, assuming there aren't any others, but this looks perfect.

Comment: @PatrickStevens: You're welcome! LaTeX 3 has simplified programming considerably, but the syntax might look strange (and greetings to Cambridge, UK -- nice city)

Comment: But pathological cases remain: `$\machine{a_1, a_2, \vdots, a_n} \neq {\machine{a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, \vdots, a_n}}^-1$`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Well, I assume it's not meant this way, of course

Comment: OK, it's a feature, not a bug :^)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - My answer has no problem with `$\machine{a_1,a_2,\vdots,a_n} \neq \machine{a_1,a_2,a_3, a_4,a_5,a_6, \vdots,a_n}^{\,-1}$`. :-)

Comment: @Mico Caught my bad syntax, I see.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use LuaLaTeX, the following solution method may be of interest to you. (It is a direct application of [@topskip's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304591/5001) to the recent query, [Split list into tabular with luatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304536/5001), adapted to the case of an `array` environment with a single, centered column.)

The code provides a TeX macro called `\machine`, which takes a single argument (a comma-separated list of entries), and a Lua function called `machine` (note: no backslash) that does most of the work.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math,luacode}

%% Lua-side code: The function 'machine' does most of the work
\begin{luacode*}
function machine ( s )
    s = string.gsub ( s, "," , "\\\\\\hline ")
    tex.sprint("\\begin{array}{|c|}\\hline ")
    tex.sprint(s , "\\\\\\hline\\end{array}")
end
\end{luacode*}
%% TeX-side code: A macro that calls the Lua function
\newcommand{\machine}[1]{\directlua{machine(\luastring{#1})}}

\begin{document}
$\machine{a_1,a_2,\vdots,a_n}$
\end{document}
```